# Disable button after form reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

After I submit an invalid form page it redirects back to the same form page.

I want to be able to disable the "Find address" button and "House No" input field.

At the moment only "House No" input stays disabled and not the "Find address" button.
Please help.

```
var enableDisableFindAddress = function(postcodeLookupAvailabilityCountries) {

    var $this              = $( ".find-address-country"),
        addressType        = $this.data( "addresstype" ),
        countryISO         = $this.val(),
        availableCountries = postcodeLookupAvailabilityCountries;

    var foundAvailableISO    = false,
        HouseNameOrNoFieldId = "#" + addressType + "_house_no_or_name",
        searchBtnID          = "#" + addressType + "_search_btn";

    for( i = 0; i < availableCountries.length; i++ ){
        if( countryISO == availableCountries[i] ){
            foundAvailableISO = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( foundAvailableISO ) {
        $( HouseNameOrNoFieldId ).prop( "disabled", false );
        $( searchBtnID ).prop( "disabled", false );
    } else {
        $( HouseNameOrNoFieldId ).prop( "disabled", true );
        $( searchBtnID ).prop( "disabled", true );
        alert("I am suppose to disable this")
    }       
}

// THIS IS NOT WORKING
if ( $( ".find-address-country").val() !== "" ) { 
    enableDisableFindAddress( postcodeLookupAvailabilityCountries );
}

// THIS IS WORKING
$( ".find-address-country" ).change( function() {
    enableDisableFindAddress( postcodeLookupAvailabilityCountries );
});
```

Comment: postcodeLookupAvailabilityCountries is undefined

Comment: Nope thats not it

Comment: The button needs to stay disabled after redirect

Comment: What's `.find-address-country` ? How do you fill it after redirect ?